# How to reset Mac App Store (to factory defaults)?

Tags: mac-appstore, macos

On Mavericks the Mac App Store started to hang right after start (when accesing menu, to be exact). How to reset it? I.e. remove some configuration files that drive the store into improper state?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete appstore cache files : `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.appstore`
This may not solve the entire issue you should look in your `/private/var/folders` and delete the com.apple.appstore forlder for me it's in `/private/var/folders/08/366wf94902jf_hy69t1d_92r0000gn/C/com.apple.appstore` It's gonna be different for you .

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't help. Are there maybe any other locations?

Comment: maybe deleting these folder could hep 
    `~/Library/Caches/storeaccountd`
    `~/Library/Caches/storeassetd`
    `~/Library/Caches/storedownloadd`
    `~/Library/Caches/storeinappd`
Quit the appstore and run this with terminal : `rm -r ~/Library/Caches/store*`

Comment: I ran those locations and also previous ones and the app store still hangs